# The significance of A.M. after a given name?

Tags: death-records, massachusetts, 1820s, abbreviations

> John [A.M. GR1], Esq., Nov. 25, 1827, a. abt. 79 y. CR1 [Nov. 24, a. 80 y. GR1]

This death entry for John Rogers is found in the [Vital Records of Gloucester, Massachusetts, vol. 3](https://ma-vitalrecords.org/MA/Essex/Gloucester/Images/Gloucester_D264.shtml).

GR1 represents a specific cemetery, First Parish Burial Ground (also known as Bridge Street Cemetery).

A.M. is not explained in the list of [Abbreviations](https://ma-vitalrecords.org/MA/Essex/Gloucester/Abbreviations.shtml) for this volume.

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! How did you access this information? It appears to combine information from two different entries.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect this refers to his degree – Master of Arts (Artium Magister), now more commonly abbreviated as M.A.

In the vital records you found this entry in, there is another John Rogers (d.1782), a Reverend (and apparently the father of your John Rogers), who also has A.M. after his name.

I could not find an image of the headstone for John Rogers d. 1827 – perhaps it doesn't survive. However, the headstone for John d. 1782 can be found on [FindAGrave](https://www.findagrave.com/memorial/55114181/john-rogers), where the letters A.M. are listed in a form consistent with a degree.

[image]

A next step to confirm this would be to identify where he studied, and see if any records survive regarding his education.

There is a John Rogers (recorded Johannes) who graduated with a Master's from Harvard University in 1767, which would be a good possibility. See [Index of Harvard graduates in the classes of 1642-1772](https://colonialnorthamerica.library.harvard.edu/spotlight/cna/catalog/990016414540203941) (see page 73):

[image]